# Tempdb becomes too big in size

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was executing one normal SP and after that my `Tempdb` acquired 80GB disk space which was only 8MB before. How can I overcome this? and Why this happened?

Comment: shrink the transaction log(you may need to backup the database first)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yeah I will shrink it but what could be the reason for this? thats the main thing I want to know.

Comment: Read the execution plan to find what is spilling to tempdb. Common ones are sort and hash operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because you did something in the SP that needed tempdb. Sorting under certain conditions, the dreaded DISTINCT that needds to know all data for example.

You can overcome this by rewriting your SQL not to use Tempdb. And the current resize you just fix (redefine size, restart server, tempdb is recreated).

Depending on the db, btw, I would NOT consider 80gb to be excessive on a decent modern server. Depends WHAT you do, obviously.

Comment: out of curiosity, does `group by` have the same problem as the `distinct` ?

Comment: I think yes. Things also depend on things like indices.